# Only one content type header should be provided error

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I have the following curl command

`curl -k -H "Content-Type :json" -H "Authorization :Bearer eH8AIKuLdQfhy6kG5I0fPBK/abNJUN89C" -XPUT https://localhost:9200/college/faculty/1 -d "
{
\"name\":\"rmg\",
\"post\":\"professor\"
}"`

but i get the following error,i am not able to figure out the solution.

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"content_type_header_exception","reason":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: only one Content-Type header should be provided"}],"type":"content_type_header_exception","reason":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: only one Content-Type header should be provided","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"only one Content-Type header should be provided"}},"status":400}`

Comment: Have you tried providing a proper header, by removing the space behind `Content-Type`?

Comment: yes i tried, it do not resolve the issue

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Try `curl -k -H 'Content-Type:application/json'`